# Connecting a NodeJS application to Estimote's Mesh Network

Tags: node.js, ibeacon, estimote, mesh-network

I have a few questions about Estimote’s mesh network and was wondering to get some help, as I have not found anything.

I have a dedicated Node.js Server running on a Samsung Artik. Is it possible for this server to communicate directly with beacons on a mesh network and listen for telemetry broadcasting?

Example:
There is one beacon in each room of my house and they are all connected in a mesh network. 
Can my server communicate with the mesh network and get data such as temperature, ambient light level, etc?